# How can I use Override Provider multiple times for different scenarios when using Nest.js to test?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

I am trying to Unit Test a file using Nest.js (and Jest), like so:

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { MyService } from 'myService';
import { DependencyService } from 'dependencyService';

describe('#mainMethod', () => {
  let myService, dependencyService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    let mockDependencyService = {
      method1: jest.fn(() => true)
    };

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
            MyService,
            DependencyService,
        ]
      })
        .overrideProvider(DependencyService).useValue(mockDependencyService)
        .compile();
  
      myService = module.get<MyService>(MyService);
      dependencyService = module.get<DependencyService>(DependencyService);
  });

  it('should be ok', () => {
    // any test
  })
});
```

When writing it like that, I am able to test a scenario where `method1` from `DependencyService` returns `true`.

What is the best way of testing a different response from `method1`? Should I wrap it all in a `BeforeEach`, create another `describe` block, change the `mockDependencyService.method1`'s return, and create the module all over again? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably mock the module like so as a normal function:

```
let mockDependencyService = {
  method1: () => true
};
```

And then spy on the instance from each test:

```
jest.spyOn(myService, 'method1').mockReturnValue(false)
myService.method1()

// useless expectation for demo purposes
expect(myService.method1).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

This lets you prep the starting circumstances for each test as each test needs.

Comment: Great, thanks!
I only need to create the **module** (and attach its mock modules) once, and can wrap that in a `beforeAll` statement.
Than, for each test, I use a `jest.spyOn` inside a `beforeEach`, with the mocked response for that scenario and a `jest.restoreAllMocks` inside an `afterEach`.

Comment: @Alex Wayne, why did you say: "like a normal function" instead of using jest.fn() wrapping it? 
I'm asking because I am facing a problem when using jest.fn inside a mockService object and useValue just like Murilo Salomão and my mock functions return undefined.
If I use normal functions without jest.fn() they work perfectly.
Another weird thing is that in other test classes I use the same, overriding the same service and it works.